# Print and evaluate in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently for my scientific experiments I use

```
dbg = print
# def dbg(*args): pass
```

So I have a lot of `dbg(x, y, f(x))` in code, all of which I can "turn off" my commenting one line and uncommenting another.

However, the output looks brief, e.g. `0 15 32`.
Is there a way to make it look like `x = 0, y = 15, f(x) = 32`?

I tried to write something using `eval`, but couldn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the `=` operator on `f-strings`:

```
dbg(f"{x=}, {y=}, {f(x)=}")
```

This was introduced in Python3.8 [f-strings support = for self-documenting expressions and debugging](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)

> Added an `=` specifier to f-strings. An f-string such as **`f'{expr=}'`** will expand to the text of the expression, an equal sign, then the representation of the evaluated expression. For example:
>
> ```py
> >>> user = 'eric_idle'
> >>> member_since = date(1975, 7, 31)
> >>> f'{user=} {member_since=}'
> "user='eric_idle' member_since=datetime.date(1975, 7, 31)"
> ```

Comment: That is so cool. I knew about f-strings but apparently somehow not about this particular feature.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time I had to write `print(f"somevar = {somevar}")`...  This is fabulous.  Too bad much of my work requires python 3.6.